# HttpHandler expiration for PivotViewer

Tags: c#, silverlight, pivotviewer

I have been trying to get my PivotViewer implementation to *NOT* cache the HttpResponse but have not been successful. How does one set the expiration of a Response object? I have been doing the following.

```
           _HttpContext.Response.Expires = 0;
           _HttpContext.Response.ExpiresAbsolute = DateTime.Now.Subtract( new TimeSpan( 1, 0, 0, 0 ) );
           _HttpContext.Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";
```

The problem is - subsequent call to display my PivotViewer always display the results of the first call. I am not using a static CXML - I am using the PivotServer tools and creating it dynamically.

What I want to know is how to set the expiry of the page so that each Pivot View request creates a HttpResponse or has the PivotViewer got a bug in it and it is ignoring cache control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you are making multiple LoadCollection() calls to the same URL and wondering why you are not getting a refresh, correct?  If that's not the case then I misunderstood.

The PivotViewer will not make a new call if the Uri string passed in the LoadCollection() is identical to the previous call.  Even adding a hash tag will not trick it.  I'm not sure if this is a performance thing or what, but it is what it is.  The only real way to reload the collection is to change the Uri.  I typically do this by adding/modifying a querystring counter.

I have an example of this in a blog post : [Reloading a Collection in PivotViewer](http://tonychampion.net/blog/index.php/2011/01/reloading-a-collection-in-the-pivotviewer/)

If you are having a different problem please let me know and we can get you fixed up.

Comment: It works when adding a counter. I could not get the page to expire using the response class.